Need Help Extending Root Filesystem Using Additional Hard Drives on IBM Cloud Server
I’m working on an IBM cloud server running Debian and need some assistance with extending my root filesystem. Here are the details:
Current Disk Layout:
lsblk output:
root@hanyg6266:~# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
xvda    202:0    0  100G  0 disk 
├─xvda1 202:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─xvda2 202:2    0   99G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0    2G  0 disk 
└─xvdb1 202:17   0    2G  0 part [SWAP]
xvdc    202:32   0  400G  0 disk 
xvde    202:64   0  400G  0 disk 
xvdh    202:112  0   64M  0 disk

blkid output:
/dev/xvda2: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="25a4ce50-0329-4893-af97-c022d6f06853" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="37c5d9ea-02"
/dev/xvda1: LABEL="cloudimg-bootfs" UUID="98f1daa5-239d-4567-9976-cea79565dd15" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="37c5d9ea-01"
/dev/xvdh: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL_FATBOOT="config-2" LABEL="config-2" UUID="9796-932E" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/xvdb1: LABEL="SWAP-xvdb1" UUID="d51fcca0-6b10-4934-a572-f3898dfd8840" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="00025cdb-01"

df -hT output:
Filesystem     Type   Size  Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted on
tmpfs          tmpfs  6.3G  1.2M  6.3G   1%    /run
/dev/xvda2     ext4    98G  1.6G   92G   2% /
tmpfs          tmpfs   32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/xvda1     ext3   975M   74M  850M   8% /boot
tmpfs          tmpfs  6.3G   12K  6.3G   1% /run/user/0

Problem:
I want to extend my root filesystem to use the additional 400GB + 400GB hard drives (/dev/xvdc and /dev/xvde). However, I can't boot from a CD or ISO due to the lack of physical access. My SSH access is restricted to the current root directory, and I need to keep it operational while extending the root filesystem.
I’ve already mounted the partitions from the additional hard drives to /home, but they are not being used to extend the root filesystem. I can’t copy or move the root directory or resync it due to SSH access limitations.
Request:
Can anyone guide me through the process of extending my root filesystem with these additional drives while keeping the system operational via SSH? Any step-by-step instructions or commands would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Not possible. A filesystem (generally) cannot span multiple extents (devices, partitions, whatever).


I want to extend my root filesystem to use the additional 400GB + 400GB hard drives (/dev/xvdc and /dev/xvde).

You're using plain ext4 without any volume management. In this setup, you cannot extend the root filesystem beyond its current partition.
Having LVM underneath the ext4 filesystem would've allowed you to have a logical disk that spans multiple partitions (added/removed on the fly), but that's not something you can insert underneath a running filesystem.
Since this is a VM, your only option for "seamless" expansion is to find a way to increase the size of the xvda disk through VM management, then grow the ext4 filesystem online.
Other than that, you have basically no options for truly seamless expansion, although there are a few that would work if you can shut down the server's services for a brief moment:

Use ncdu -x / to find the largest non-system directories in your root filesystem, then move them to one of your new disks (wherever it is mounted) and symlink or bind-mount them back to the original location.
This can be done fast, first by copying the directory, then shutting down the service that uses it, rsyncing any final changes, moving the old directory aside (faster than removing it), then creating the symlink or bind-mount and starting the service again.

Create a second cloud server, one with a larger rootfs partition (or with LVM), copy your rootfs there, make sure it boots and everything, move the IP address to the new server, destroy the old one.



I can’t copy or move the root directory or resync it due to SSH access limitations.

SSH doesn't impose any such limitations. (If the server's admins have set up some kind of "limited root" using SELinux, then you need to get them to do the work instead...)

However, I can't boot from a CD or ISO due to the lack of physical access

A good cloud hosting service should offer booting from ISO image, since VMs are always capable of that.
With console (bootloader) access it's possible to get around this problem, by configuring GRUB on disk 1 to boot something like a temporary OS from disk 2, but this is not easy to write step-by-step instructions for.

Thank You so much for this detailed and logical reply. I understood it completely.
